# Closest subsequent index for a specified value

Tags: r, vector, indexing, position, distance

Consider a vector:

```r
int = c(1, 1, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 2)
```

I'd like to get the closest subsequent index (not the difference) for a specified value. The first parameter of the function should be the vector, while the second should be the value one wants to see the closest subsequent elements.

For instance,

```r
f(int, 0)
# [1] 2 1 0 2 1 0 0 NA
```

Here, the first element of the vector (1) is two positions away from the first subsequent 0, (3 - 1 = 2), so it should return 2. Then the second element is 1 position away from a 0 (2 - 1 = 1). When there is no subsequent values that match the specified value, return NA (here it's the case for the last element, because no subsequent value is 0).

Other examples:

```r
f(int, 1)
# [1] 0 0 NA NA NA NA NA NA

f(int, 2) 
# [1] 4 3 2 1 0 2 1 0

f(int, 3) 
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

This should also work for character vectors:

```r
char = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A")

f(char, "A") 
# [1] 0 2 1 0 0
```

Comment: In your last char example, could you explain the output, why are we getting 0,2,1,0,0 ?

Comment: Yes. `f` should return the closest following value that equals "A". So first the value of char, "A", this is 0, for the second, it is 2, because B is 2-position away from the following "A" (4-2 = 2). Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Find the location of each value (numeric or character)

```
int = c(1, 1, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 2)
value = 0
idx = which(int == value)
## [1] 3 6 7
```

Expand the index to indicate the nearest value of interest, using an NA after the last value in `int`.

```
nearest = rep(NA, length(int))
nearest[1:max(idx)] = rep(idx, diff(c(0, idx))),
## [1]  3  3  3  6  6  6  7 NA
```

Use simple arithmetic to find the difference between the index of the current value and the index of the nearest value

```
abs(seq_along(int) - nearest)
## [1]  2  1  0  2  1  0  0 NA
```

Written as a function

```
f <- function(x, value) {
    idx = which(x == value)
    nearest = rep(NA, length(x))
    if (length(idx)) # non-NA values only if `value` in `x`
        nearest[1:max(idx)] = rep(idx, diff(c(0, idx)))
    abs(seq_along(x) - nearest)
}
```

We have

```
> f(int, 0)
[1]  2  1  0  2  1  0  0 NA
> f(int, 1)
[1]  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA
> f(int, 2)
[1] 4 3 2 1 0 2 1 0
> f(char, "A")
[1] 0 2 1 0 0
> f(char, "B")
[1]  1  0 NA NA NA
> f(char, "C")
[1]  2  1  0 NA NA
```

The solution doesn't involve recursion or R-level loops, so should e fast even for long vectors.

Answer (score 11):

Look for the match from nth position to the end of the vector, then get the 1st match:

```
f <- function(v, x){
  sapply(seq_along(v), function(i){
    which(v[ i:length(v) ] == x)[ 1 ] - 1
  })
}

f(int, 0)
# [1]  2  1  0  2  1  0  0 NA
f(int, 1)
# [1]  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA
f(int, 2)
# [1] 4 3 2 1 0 2 1 0
f(int, 3) 
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

f(char, "A") 
# [1] 0 2 1 0 0
```

Comment: beautiful! I thought the only elegant answer would have been a recursive function but yours is elegant as well.

Comment: @sbarbit to be honest, recursive solution didn't even come to my mind.

Answer (score 9):

Using `sequence`:

```r
f <- function(v, x){
  d = diff(c(0, which(v == x)))
  vec <- sequence(d, d-1, by = -1)
  length(vec) <- length(int)
  vec
}
```

**Output**

```r
int = c(1, 1, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 2)
char = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A")

f(int, 0)
# [1]  2  1  0  2  1  0  0 NA

f(int, 1)
# [1]  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA

f(int, 2)
# [1] 4 3 2 1 0 2 1 0

f(char, "A")
# [1] 0 2 1 0 0
```

---

**Benchmark** (n = 1000):

```r
set.seed(123)
int = sample(0:100, size = 1000, replace = T)

library(microbenchmark)
bm <- microbenchmark(
  fSequence(int, 0),
  fzx8754(int, 0),
  fRecursive(int, 0), 
  fMartinMorgan(int, 0), 
  fMap2dbl(int, 0),
  fReduce(int, 0),
  fAve(int, 0),
  fjblood94(int, 0),
  times = 10L,
  setup = gc(FALSE)
)
autoplot(bm)
```

Martin Morgan's solution seems to be the quickest, followed by this answer's `sequence` solution, sbarbit's recursive solution, and jblood94's for loop solution.
[image]

Functions used:

```r
fSequence <- function(v, x){
  vec <- sequence(diff(c(0, which(v == x))), diff(c(0, which(v == x))) - 1, by = -1)
  length(vec) <- length(v)
  vec
}

fzx8754 <- function(v, x){
  sapply(seq_along(v), function(i){
    which(v[ i:length(v) ] == x)[ 1 ] - 1
  })
}

fRecursive <- function(lookup,val ) {
  ind <- which(lookup == val)[1] -1
  if (length(lookup) > 1) {
    c(ind, f(lookup[-1], val))
  } else {
    ind
  }
}

fMartinMorgan <- function(x, value) {
  idx = which(x == value)
  nearest = rep(NA, length(x))
  nearest[1:max(idx)] = rep(idx, diff(c(0, idx)))
  abs(seq_along(x) - nearest)
}

fMap2dbl <- function(int, num)
{
  n <- length(int)
  
  map2_dbl(num, 1:n, ~ ifelse(length(which(.x == int[.y:n])) == 0, NA, 
                              min(which(.x == int[.y:n])) - 1))
}

fReduce <- function(vec, value) {
  replace(
    Reduce(
      function(x, y)
        x  + (y * x) ,
      vec != value,
      right = TRUE,
      accumulate = TRUE
    ),
    max(tail(which(vec == value), 1), 0) < seq_along(vec),
    NA
  )
}

fAve <- function(init, k) {
  ave(
    seq_along(init),
    c(0, head(cumsum(init == k), -1)),
    FUN = function(x) if (any(x == k)) rev(seq_along(x) - 1) else NA
  )
}

fjblood94 <- function(v, val) {
  out <- integer(length(v))
  if (v[length(v)] != val) out[length(v)] <- NA_integer_
  
  for (i in (length(v) - 1L):1) {
    if (v[i] == val) {
      out[i] <- 0L
    } else {
      out[i] <- out[i + 1L] + 1L
    }
  }
  
  return(out)
}
```

Comment: `sequence` is really efficient, upvoted! Also, love the benchmarking!

Comment: Interesting, all my benchmarking shows `fSequence` as the clear winner, which is what I would have expected.

Comment: Interesting indeed. What about when you replicate my benchmarking analysis?

Answer (score 6):

Here `f` is defined as a recursive function that calls itself over shorter tails of the `lookup` vector:

```r
f <- function(lookup,val ) {
  ind <- which(lookup == val)[1] -1
  if (length(lookup) > 1) {
    c(ind, f(lookup[-1], val))
  } else {
    ind
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice recursive solution.

Comment: well.. being on stack overflow kind of inspired me :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach using `Reduce()` and then some fiddling to get the `NA` values.

```
f <- function(vec, value) {
replace(
  Reduce(
    function(x, y)
      x  + (y * x) ,
    vec != value,
    right = TRUE,
    accumulate = TRUE
  ),
  max(tail(which(vec == value), 1), 0) < seq_along(vec),
  NA
)
}

f(int, 0)          
[1]  2  1  0  2  1  0  0 NA

f(int, 1)          
[1]  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA

f(int, 2) 
[1] 4 3 2 1 0 2 1 0

f(int, 3) 
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

char = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A")

f(char, "A") 
[1] 0 2 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::map2_dbl`:

```r
library(purrr)

int = c(1, 1, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 2)

f <- function(int, num)
{
  n <- length(int)
  
  map2_dbl(num, 1:n, ~ ifelse(length(which(.x == int[.y:n])) == 0, NA, 
      min(which(.x == int[.y:n])) - 1))
}

f(int, 0)
#> [1]  2  1  0  2  1  0  0 NA

f(int, 1)          
#> [1]  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA

f(int, 2) 
#> [1] 4 3 2 1 0 2 1 0

f(int, 3) 
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

char = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A")

f(char, "A") 
#> [1] 0 2 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 5):

A single-pass `for` loop is simple and efficient:

```
f1 <- function(v, val) {
  out <- integer(length(v))
  if (v[length(v)] != val) out[length(v)] <- NA_integer_
  
  for (i in (length(v) - 1L):1) {
    if (v[i] == val) {
      out[i] <- 0L
    } else {
      out[i] <- out[i + 1L] + 1L
    }
  }
  
  return(out)
}

int <- c(1, 1, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 2)
chr <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A")
f1(int, 0)
#> [1]  2  1  0  2  1  0  0 NA
f1(chr, "A")
#> [1] 0 2 1 0 0
```

Benchmarking against other solutions:

```
f2 <- function(v, x){
  sapply(seq_along(v), function(i){
    which(v[ i:length(v) ] == x)[ 1 ] - 1
  })
}

f3 <- function(lookup,val ) {
  ind <- which(lookup == val)[1] -1
  if (length(lookup) > 1) {
    c(ind, f3(lookup[-1], val))
  } else {
    ind
  }
}

f4 <- function(x, value) {
  idx = which(x == value)
  nearest = rep(NA, length(x))
  nearest[1:max(idx)] = rep(idx, diff(c(0, idx)))
  abs(seq_along(x) - nearest)
}

f5 <- function(vec, value) {
  replace(
    Reduce(
      function(x, y)
        x  + (y * x) ,
      vec != value,
      right = TRUE,
      accumulate = TRUE
    ),
    max(tail(which(vec == value), 1), 0) < seq_along(vec),
    NA
  )
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = {f1(int, 0); f1(chr, "A")},
                               f2 = {f2(int, 0); f2(chr, "A")},
                               f3 = {f3(int, 0); f3(chr, "A")},
                               f4 = {f4(int, 0); f4(chr, "A")},
                               f5 = {f5(int, 0); f5(chr, "A")},
                               check = "equal")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr  min    lq   mean median    uq   max neval
#>    f1  6.0  7.50  8.990   8.40  9.60  18.3   100
#>    f2 54.2 61.45 71.752  65.55 79.40 131.8   100
#>    f3 25.5 28.60 33.393  30.75 35.90 105.2   100
#>    f4 22.3 26.30 30.599  28.00 32.65  82.4   100
#>    f5 59.7 64.55 73.474  69.10 75.70 157.0   100
```

Comment: Nice to see the benchmark! If I try `int = sample(0:5, 1000, replace = TRUE)` I get `Error: C stack usage  7975244 is too close to the limit` from the recursive (`f3()`) version, so that doesn't scale well. Removing it, `f1()` and `f4()` are one or two orders of magnitude faster than the others, and for me `f4()` is twice as fast as `f1()` (111 vs 223 microseconds); for a vector of length 10000, `f4()` is a little more than 3x faster than `f1()`.

Answer (score 5):

A base R option using `ave` + `cumsum`

```
f <- function(init, k) {
  ave(
    seq_along(init),
    c(0, head(cumsum(init == k), -1)),
    FUN = function(x) if (any(x == k)) rev(seq_along(x) - 1) else NA
  )
}
```

and you will see

```
> f(init, 0)
[1]  2  1  0  2  1  0  0 NA

> f(init, 1)
[1]  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA

> f(init, 2)
[1] 4 3 2 1 0 2 1 0

> f(init, 3)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```